# UrlMapping to Index is not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to get my Index which in my case is just localhost:8080 to go to a different page. This code is not working and I'm just going to the index page instead of rendering "this worked"

My UrlMappings file looks like this:

```
package appworld

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/" {
            controller = "Home"
            action = "isUserLoggedIn"
        }

        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

The method in HomeController.groovy looks like:

```
def isUserLoggedIn() {
   println("We made it from index")
   render "this worked"
}
```

Comment: Do you have spring security installed? If so then use a different name for your method. I bet that will fix the issue.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I don't have spring security installed, I also tried changing the name of the method (I changed UrlMappings.groovy to mirror that) and got no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your syntax is off.  Try:

```
"/"(controller:"home", action:"isUserLoggedIn")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Can't believe I missed something that simple lol